# лишний символ при чтении из UTF-8 файла в Set (java)

Tags: java

Яву учу первый месяц урывками, хочу разобраться.
Это часть моего тестового задания чтобы поступить курсы по java.

у меня есть текстовый файл dict.txt

```
текст
виде
изображение
файл
```

я пытаюсь сделать с ним это:

```js
final String dictfile = "dict.txt";
Set<String> slovar = new HashSet<String>();
        try {
            slovar.addAll(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(dictfile), Charset.defaultCharset()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(slovar); //[текст, изображение, файл, виде]
```

в консоли выводится [·текст, изображение, файл, виде]
что это за точка "·" перед словом "текст"?
откуда она берется и как мне поправить код/руки чтобы в slovar считывалось именно то что содержится в файле?

файл dict.txt UTF-8 лишних пробелов до и после слова "текст" нет.

---

P.S. пробовал по другому, результат тот же: [·текст, изображение, файл, виде]

```js
        final String dictfile = "dict.txt";
        Set<String> slovarr = new HashSet<String>();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dictfile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    slovarr.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(slovarr);
```

Comment: мне кажется дело в файле, не правильная кодировка или что то такое.  с кодом тут полный порядок

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov благодарю, пойду копать кодировки...

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov нет при смене кодировок становиться только хуже ошибки компилятора и не читаемый  вывод в консоли:[⥪��, ����ࠦ����, 䠩�, ����]

Comment: У вас файл битый, попробуйте другой создайте, и скопируйте то что вы написали в вопросе. + писать  Charset.defaultCharset() смысла особого нет, если вы не задаете кодировку явно, то используется кодировка по дефолту, т.е. то что вы передаете.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov старый файл удалил, создал новый, результат тот же...  про Charset.defaultCharset() я так и думал.

Comment: у меня ваша ошибка не воспроизводится

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov все-таки вы оказались правы: дело было в файле: .в начале UTF файла есть символ BOM(Byte Order Mark) и с помощью Notepad++ можно сохранить файл в UTF без BOM.

Answer (score 3):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211589/error1-1illegalcharacter-ufeff-when-compiling-on-android-studio), оказывается:

1.точка что мне не нравилась называется \uFEFF

2.в начале UTF-8 файла есть символ BOM(Byte Order Mark) и с помощью Notepad++(в Windows) или Notepadqq(в Linux) можно сохранить файл в UTF без BOM. (Меню Encoding > Convert to UTF-8 without BOM)

на неруском:
That's a problem related to BOM (Byte Order Mark) character. Byte Order Mark BOM is a Unicode character used for defining a text file byte order and comes in the start of the file. Eclipse doesn't allow this character at the start of your file, so you must delete it. For this purpose, use a rich text editor, such as Notepad++, and save the file with encoding "UTF-8 without BOM." That should remove the problem.